# What is the difference between monopoly profit and monopoly rent?

Tags: monopoly

I understand that monopoly profit is the return on capital (=profit) of the monopolist, which is larger than the normal profit in a competitive market.
As monopoly rent I understand the income in excess of the factor cost (=rent) of the monopolist.
In this sense both would refer to the same thing.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Economic (not just monopoly) rent is what is otherwise known as produces surplus. And producer surplus is related to profit via

$$\text{Producer Surplus}=\text{Profit}+\text{Fixed Cost}$$

assuming that fixed cost is sunk.

Comment: Thank you. But isn't economic rent typically understood as payment "in excess of the costs needed to bring that factor into production”? In a long term perspective a decision will be made whether or not to incur Fixed Costs. That would imply that in the long term Profit and (monopoly) rent/Producer Surplus do correspond.(?)

Comment: @Steve222: Note that the equation I gave assumes that fixed costs are *sunk*. In the long run there is no sunk cost, so profit is the same as producer surplus.